# extjs4 combobox trunks value

Tags: combobox, extjs4.1

I have a comboBox within  a form, the valueField is the ObjectId field of a document in mongodb, it displays the proper value of the fields in the comboBox, but it returns just a part of the value with getValue, getRawValue returns the value of the displayField.
This is the code of the comboBox:

```
{
        xtype: 'combo',
        fieldLabel:'Firm',
        store:Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('bbCompaniesStore'),
        displayField: 'firm',
        valueField: '_id',
        name: 'country',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        cls: 'field-margin',
        flex: 1
    }
```

This is how I get the value from the form:

```
var nomeField = formPanel.items.get(0).items.get(0);
var firmField = formPanel.items.get(0).items.get(1);
var noteField = formPanel.items.get(0).items.get(2);
var contact = Ext.ModelManager.create({nome: nomeField.getValue(), note: noteField.getValue(),'firm_id':firmField.getValue()}, 'Contact');
```

It works but it trunks the value of _id, I checked with firebug, the server sends the rigth data,I think that extjs does some kind of normalization, before I solved using getRawValue, but with combobox it returns the displayField. I do not know how to fix  this problem.

Comment: What your id looks like? How is your store definition (or model if apply)? I think the problem may be the type of id you're using (the type of the field on the model).

Comment: my model is: Ext.define('Company',
 {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
   {
     name: '_id',
     type: 'int'
   },
   {
    name:'firm'
   },
   {
    name:'note'
   },
   { 
    name:'paese'
   }
   
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'data/companies/'
    }

 }
 ); while my id is auto generated by mongodb: "513e727e44ae2025845e6efb"

Comment: do you tried making id type as string

Comment: thanks, I did nothing to the Id

Comment: Well, you say you did nothing to id but that is a hash and you have it in your model as int, that is the problem, change it to: ` { name: '_id', type: 'string' }`, that should do the trick for you.